# HLSL (compute shader, shader model 5_1) conundrum

Tags: gpgpu, hlsl, compute-shader, directx-12

So I had this HLSL structure that compiled successfully in VS2015 when used:

```
struct SpatialHashingCellData
{
    uint count;
    uint specks[MAX_SPECKS_PER_CELL];
};
```

It was used like this:

```
    gSPCells[cellID].specks[posToWrite]= speckIndex;
```

But then I switched to VS2017 and I had to make this change in order for it to compile because there was an error:
***internal error : l-value expected***

```
struct SpatialHashingCellData
{
    uint count;
    struct { uint index; } specks[MAX_SPECKS_PER_CELL];
};
```

... and changed:

```
    gSPCells[cellID].specks[posToWrite].index = speckIndex;
```

I feel kinda stupid for not knowing what is happening here. Hope anyone could clear this out for me, please :)

Best regards,
Bojan

Comment: This sounds like a compiler bug. Your best chance is to isolate the failure in a simple hlsl sample file with a fxc command line and post a bug report on the microsoft DirectX forum : http://forums.directxtech.com/index.php